# How to resize image with imagebox emgucv?

Tags: c#-3.0, face-detection

I  have image in folder image
how resize image with imagebox in emgucv at open image?
thnx..

Answer (score 8):

```
// To get orginal image from the OpenFileDialog
Image<Bgr, Byte> captureImage = new Image<Bgr, byte>(openImageFileDialog.FileName);

// To resize the image 
Image<Bgr, byte> resizedImage = captureImage.Resize(width, height, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_LINEAR);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: As far as I know, it isn't possible resize in place (that is, resize an image and affect the image which calls the resize) using Emgu CV. e.g. you need to do: ```var im = new Image<Gray, byte>(filename); ... logic ... im = im.Resize(...)``` rather than ```var im = new Image<Gray, byte>(filename) ... logic ... im.Resize(...)```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is very simple.

Let us suppose the path of image is "C:\image.jpg".

```
Mat frame = new Mat();   //Declaration
string path = @"C:\image.jpg";
int width = 640, height = 480;

frame = CvInvoke.Imread(path , LoadImageType.AnyColor);

CvInvoke.Resize(frame, frame, new Size(imagebox1.Width, imagebox1.Height), 0, 0, Inter.Linear);    //This resizes the image to the size of Imagebox1 
OR
CvInvoke.Resize(frame, frame, new Size(width, height), 0, 0, Inter.Linear);    //This resizes the image into your specified width and height
```

Answer (score 0):

This is How i resized image using  EmguCV

```
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream);
            Image<Hsv, Byte> Iimage = new Image<Hsv, byte>(bitmap);
            Image<Hsv, Byte> HsvImage = Iimage.Resize(384, 256,INTER.CV_INTER_LINEAR);
```